# Linear Regression Apache Spark with Scala not even straight line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I want to apologize for my really stupid question but I have a problem with my Linear Regression. I`m struggling with that a lot. Could you please help me.

This is my main code. I`m currently using some external library to plot the data.

```
import com.fundtrml.config.ConfigSetUp
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SimpleLinearRegression {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ConfigSetUp.HadoopBinariesConfig();

    val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("DataSet Test")
      .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import ss.implicits._

    var listOfData = List(40, 41, 45, 43, 42, 60, 61, 59, 50, 49, 47, 39, 41, 37, 36, 34, 33, 37)
    val data =  listOfData  //(1 to 21 by 1)                      // create a collection of Doubles
      .map(n => (n, n))                               // make it pairs
      .map { case (label, features) =>
      LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(features)) } // create labeled points of dense vectors
      .toDF                                           // make it a DataFrame
    var splittedData = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6,0.4))
    var trainingData = splittedData(0)
    var testSetData = splittedData(1)

    trainingData.show()
    val lr = new LinearRegression()
        .setMaxIter(10)
        .setRegParam(0.3)
        .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

    //train
    val model = lr.fit(trainingData)
    println(s"model.intercept: ${model.intercept}")
    println(s"model.coefficients : ${model.coefficients}")
    // Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
    val trainingSummary = model.summary
    println(s"numIterations: ${trainingSummary.totalIterations}")
    println(s"objectiveHistory: [${trainingSummary.objectiveHistory.mkString(",")}]")
    trainingSummary.residuals.show()
    println(s"RMSE: ${trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError}")
    println(s"r2: ${trainingSummary.r2}")

    val predictions = model.transform(testSetData)
    predictions.show()

    //Display the data
    import com.quantifind.charts.Highcharts._
    regression(listOfData) //using this external library with embeded functionality about regression

    var currentPredictions = predictions.select("prediction").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList
    println(currentPredictions)
//    regression(currentPredictions.map(_.toString.toDouble))
  }
}
```

My training set is as follows, label column - value, which should be predicted, features- value, which should be used to make a prediction:

```
+-----+--------+
|label|features|
+-----+--------+
| 43.0|  [43.0]|
| 45.0|  [45.0]|
| 42.0|  [42.0]|
| 60.0|  [60.0]|
| 50.0|  [50.0]|
| 59.0|  [59.0]|
| 61.0|  [61.0]|
| 47.0|  [47.0]|
| 49.0|  [49.0]|
| 41.0|  [41.0]|
| 34.0|  [34.0]|
+-----+--------+
```

Evaluating the regression model, I`m getting the following data:

```
model.intercept: 1.7363839862169372
model.coefficients : [0.9640297102666925]
numIterations: 3
objectiveHistory: [0.5,0.406233822167566,0.031956224821402285]
RMSE: 0.29784178261548705
r2: 0.9987061382565019 --> Extremely High Close to 1
```

At the end I`m getting the following predictions:

```
+-----+--------+------------------+
|label|features|        prediction|
+-----+--------+------------------+
| 40.0|  [40.0]| 40.29757239688463|
| 41.0|  [41.0]|41.261602107151326|
| 39.0|  [39.0]|39.333542686617946|
| 36.0|  [36.0]|36.441453555817866|
| 37.0|  [37.0]| 37.40548326608456|
| 33.0|  [33.0]| 33.54936442501779|
| 37.0|  [37.0]| 37.40548326608456|
+-----+--------+------------------+
```

It is really easy to see that the predictions are not on the same line. It`s impossible to be located on the straight line.
[This is whole data set, plotted using the Scala Library- WISP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqW9B.png)

[Predicted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMWWo.png)

[Expected result, but done with the WISP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YGND.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've plotted there seem to be the label on the Y axis and the index in the list on the X axis, not the feature value on the X axis.

The predictions are indeed on the same line when plotted feature-vs-prediction. Here's what I get when doing so: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS23jnaWhKN33zA8ulW57PSzPemqEjXZ_uiLfrZyCk1Sx65LHl-CkCYwWlB8W231XOI4R6zDwBmL0ce/pubchart?oid=129467529&format=interactive)

Comment: Maybe I`m too stupid but, I think that all predicted data should be located on one straight line.

Comment: Could you please take a look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YGND.png, If this is what should be the result of the Linear Regression.  I have done this with the embedded functionality of WISP. For example, give me the prediction for 45, and it should return the X, where it close 45.

Comment: If my question is to stupid, I really apologize for that and Ignore it :)

Comment: You are not showing the result of the linear regression there. Take a look at the X-axis values. You fit the regression label against the feature. And you are plotting the label against an array index, not the feature. If you do a linear regression involving A and B, then plot A and C, of course you don't get a straight line.

Comment: Then I should add ID(1...n) in features not the same value as a Label?

Comment: Sure, you could do `.zipWithIndex` to do that. Just make sure when you're plotting it, you plot that same column and not just the resulting array's index, as it will be different after you sample out the test set.

Comment: Thanks, I will try It tomorrow, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it. I have another question my data is in the form [Date, Value],[Date, Value]. Do you think that it will be good to convert Date to Index with .zipWithIndex or to Convert Date in timestamp?